# Using regex with str.split JavaScript and parsing them separately

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to separate this one by one

`Sephora26:theactor424@gmail.com:shpk335$A:what’s your name?:actor Dawg4075:dawg648@yahoo.com:Thoiland3:what’s your favorite pet?:cat Thrive65:evergreen45@hotmail.com:gcap1078!:what’s your favorite artist:Ed sheeran`

I tried using JavaScript `str.split()` but it only parsed the first character (sephora26). What I want is to be able to parse the email and password out of it

Answer (score 1):

Does it look like something you're looking for?

```js
const strings = `Sephora26:theactor424@gmail.com:shpk335$A:what’s your name?:actor
Dawg4075:dawg648@yahoo.com:Thoiland3:what’s your favorite pet?:cat
hrive65:evergreen45@hotmail.com:gcap1078!:what’s your favorite artist:Ed sheeran`

const lines = strings.split('\n');
lines.forEach((line) => {
  [name,email,password,question,answer] = line.split(":");
  console.log(`name=${name}, email=${email}, password=${password}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn’t work

Comment: Can you help me handle one line then I will loop it, I mean code that will split data on one line then will loop it

Comment: Maybe I can help if you explain a little bit more, about what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you need to put parsed data somewhere or show it or something else?

Comment: In a case like this “Sephora26:theactor424@gmail.com:shpk335$A:what’s your name?:actor” I want to be able to parse (theactor424@gmail.com:shpk335$A) only i.e email:password only

Comment: `[,email,password] = line.split(":");`
will give you second and third elements to be assigned to `email` and `password` vars